# How do I interrupt a splash screen using onTouchListener or onTouchEvent?

Tags: android, touch-event, ontouchlistener

public class Splash extends Activity {

MediaPlayer ourSong;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle Samiloveschicken) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(Samiloveschicken);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
    ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.splashsound);
    ourSong.start();


    final Thread timer = new Thread(){


        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(5000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            finally{
                Intent openMainActivity = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
                Splash.this.startActivity(openMainActivity);
                Splash.this.finish();
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.mainfadein, R.anim.splashfadeout);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();

}



@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ourSong.release();
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}


    }
```

I'm a beginner and I've tried onClickListener, and other various things to no avail.
I can't seem to know where to put this method. I was to be able to interrupt the sleep(5000) when the screen is touched.

Comment: I want to be able to interrupt the sleep****

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set a global flag called interruptThread = false;

Then in on the onTouchListener() you can set interruptThread = true;

and before your sleep(5000); do a check

```
if(interruptThread) { 
   thread.interrupt(); 
} else { 
  sleep(5000); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, this may help you.......

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
{

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        ontouch = true;
        startActivity(new Intent(your next activity));
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return false;

};
```